# Proving $F(x, y, z)=\max(0, x+y+z-2)$ is a valid cummulative distribution function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to prove that the cummulative density function $F(x, y, z)=\max(0, x+y+z-2)$ is valid (i.e there is a density that induces it) subject to $0\leq x, y, z \leq 1$. Clearly, $F(1,1,1)=1$ and $F(0, y, z)=F(x, 0, z)=F(x, y, 0)=0$. In addition, the function is increasing on $x,y,z$, and is right continuous for each of them. Is this enough to conclude that this is a valid CDF?

Answer (score 1):

I think the condition is not enough to conclude that this is a valid CDF.

If it is, let $F(x,y,z)=P(X\le x, Y \le y, Z \le z)$, and
$$
\begin{align}
&P(\frac{1}{2} \le X \le 1, \frac{1}{2} \le Y \le 1, \frac{1}{2} \le Z \le 1) \\
= &F(1,1,1)-3F(1,1,\frac{1}{2})+3F(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})-F(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) \\ = &1-\frac{3}{2}<0 \end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The function

$$ \max \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i -n+1, 0 \right ) $$

over a unit hypercube is called the Fréchet–Hoeffding lower bound. It is a bivariate cdf for $n=2$, but for $n>2$, it is not a cdf, because it is **not** *n-increasing*, while it is increasing in each argument.

For an $n$-dimensional multivariate cdf $F$, **the condition of being increasing (in each argument) is replaced by being $n$-increasing**, that is, for any hypercube $B=\prod_{i=1}^{n}[a_i,b_i]\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $,

$$\sum_{\boldsymbol{w}\in \prod_{i=1}^{n}\{a_i,b_i\}} (-1)^{N(\boldsymbol{w})} F(\boldsymbol{x})\ge 0$$

with $N(\boldsymbol{w})=\#\{k : w_k=a_k\}$.

This implies that the probability of each hypercube is non-negative. When the function $F$ is differentiable, it is equivalent to $\frac{\partial ^n F(\boldsymbol{x})}{\partial x_1 \dots\partial x_n}\ \ge 0$ for any $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n.$

Other conditions are very similar to the univariate case.

In sum, an $n$-dimensional multivariate function $F$ is a cdf if and only if

1. it is n-increasing
2. it is right continuous
3. $ \lim_{x_i \rightarrow -\infty} F(x_1,...,x_n)=0$ for each $i$
4. $ \lim_{\boldsymbol{x} \rightarrow +\infty} F(\boldsymbol{x})=1.$